# how to make the program close if the turtle hits a line

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics

is there a way to make the turtle program close if it touches the a line on the screen? im trying to make a game a bit like tron, but I need to get the program to close if anyone hits a line so far I have done the main part:

```
from tkinter import *
from turtle import *
import turtle
import webbrowser
import time


tess = turtle.Turtle()
alex = turtle.Turtle()


tess.width(1)
tess.color("red")
alex.color("blue")
alex.width(1)
turtle.setup(500,600)
wn = turtle.Screen() 
wn.title("Draw whith lines!!") 
wn.bgcolor("black")

def h1():
    yes = ("yes")
    while yes in ("yes"):
      tess.forward(10)
      alex.forward(10)
      time.sleep(0.5)

def h2():

  tess.left(90)

def h3():
  tess.right(90)

def ha():
  alex.left(90)

def hd():
  alex.right(90)

wn.onkey(h1, "Up")
wn.onkey(h2, "Left")
wn.onkey(h3, "Right")
wn.onkey(ha, "a")
wn.onkey(hd, "d")
wn.listen()
wn.mainloop()
```

now I just need to do the closing down and showing who won but I cant figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

Your turtles only moves by 10px steps and turn at right angles, so you have a grid where turtles can go. You «just» have to mark every cell where a turtle go and check if this cell have already be marked. You will also need to remember what is the orientation of each turtle. The tricky part is from a cell (i,j) and an orientation  calculate the new cell (i',j') where the turtle is.

Tip: with orientation as (dx,dy), dx,dy in [-1,0,1] it is quite easy.